# Prevent bootstraping of data in grails data source update mode

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

How to prevent bootstraping of data in grails app. when we configured our DataSource.groovy like this

```
 development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        username = "root"
        password = "root"
    }
```

}

**BootStrap.groovy**

```
class BootStrap {
def bootstrapService
def grailsApplication
def init = { servletContext ->
    switch (Environment.getCurrent().name) {
        case "dev":
            bootstrapService.bootstrapDummyData()
            break;
        case "test":
            bootstrapService.bootstrapDummyData()
            break;
    }
}
def destroy = {
}
```

I want `bootstrapService.bootstrapDummyData()` not to be called when i configrued my datasource to update mode. i.e. `dbCreate = "update"`

Comment: can you please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: I configured DataSource.groovy in update mode. when i run my grails- app it called the BootStrap.groovy which will result in unique constraints validation in database. because already i have data in my database. so i want when i run grails-app in update mode then it shoul not called BootStrap.groovy.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some code in your bootstrap which creates some DB entities? Please include your `Boostrap.groovy` code in the question (see edit link). One way is to check if the entity exists (search for some unique contrstraint) and only create the entitiy if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there any way in grails by which we restrict our application to call BootStrap.groovy.

Comment: Not that I know of. You can detect the running dev/test/prod envornment and only run some code for (say) the `dev` environment. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments -> `Environment.current`

Comment: You can use `findOrSaveWhere` when creating objects or just verify that nothing exists before adding data, like `if(!DomainClass.count()) proceed()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class BootStrap {
 def bootstrapService
 def grailsApplication
 def init = { servletContext -> 
 if(grailsApplication.config.dataSource.dbCreate == "create-drop"){
    switch (Environment.getCurrent().name) {
        case "dev":
            bootstrapService.bootstrapDummyData()
            break;
        case "test":
            bootstrapService.bootstrapDummyData()
            break;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: we can access dataSource dbCreate property by grailsAppliation. so this code works if you dont want to call your bootstrap code when you set your dbCreate="update"

Answer (score 0):

```
def init(){

    if(User.list().size()==0)
       objectCreation()
}

def objectCreation(){

def userObject1 = new User()
def userObject2 = new User()


}
```

the above code for example. if user is created in bootstarp . first check user is already created or not. If not create object.